# Remove SPAN with same text into an array of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have an array of DOM elements, basically, a bunch of tags coming from an API that can be duplicated or even triplicate, what I need to do is to remove from the dom all the duplicates keeping just one span. Before removing the repeated elements (SPANS) from the DOM I have to basically delete all the spaces and transform them into lowercase because I have cases like:

```
<span class="tag">Wildz</span>
<span class="tag">German</span>
<span class="tag">wilds</span>
<span class="tag">W ilds</span>
```

The idea in this case is to remove all the duplicates and leave just one. Please note that I can't remove elements by class since there are other elements that can't be removed with the same class name (eg. German).

```
const incomingChatTags = $(incomingChat).find('.tag').toArray();
//Transforming to Lowercase and removing blank space
incomingChatTags = incomingChatTags.map(tag => tag.text().toLowerCase.replace(/ /g,''))
```

The problem with this approach is that my incomingChatTags array is now a strings array and not a DOM element array so i can loop through the array and traverse the dom and remove elements. I need to have just one tag per text in order to do something like this:

```
for (let k = 0; k < incomingChatTags.length; k++) {
      const normalHolderTag = $(incomingChatTags[k]);
      switch (normalHolderTag) {
        case 'accountclosure':
          $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-accountclosure');
          $(incomingChatTags[k])
            .closest('div')
            .prepend($(incomingChatTags[k]));
          priorityVal += 200;
          break;
        case 'rg':
          $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-rg');
          priorityVal += 240;
          $(incomingChatTags[k])
            .closest('div')
            .prepend($(incomingChatTags[k]));
          break;
        case 'vip':
          $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-vip');
          $(incomingChatTags[k])
            .closest('div')
            .prepend($(incomingChatTags[k]));
          priorityVal += 300;
          break;
        case '21com': {
          const logo21 = chrome.extension.getURL('/images/21_thumb.png');
          $(incomingChatTags[k]).html(`<img src="${logo21}" />`);
          $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-tag-logo');
          break;
        }
        default:
          break;
      }    
}
```

Any ideas will be really appreciated I have tried a different kinds of approaches but almost all of the cases deal with string arrays and not with dom element arrays.

As requested by @Zohir here's the real HTML structure, the section when I have the repeated tags is the one with the class 'visitorlist_tags':

```
<div class="meshim_dashboard_components_visitors_visitorList_renderers_Incoming">
    <div class="visitor_table" data-test-id="incomingVisitor">
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div name_cell" data-test-id="nameCell">
            Natewillis925
        </div>
        <div class="icons_cell" data-test-id="iconsCell">
            <div class="meshim_dashboard_components_widgets_Browser">
                <div class="jx_ui_html_div browser Chrome" data-test-id="browserIcon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="meshim_dashboard_components_widgets_Platform">
                <div data-test-id="platformIcon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="meshim_dashboard_components_widgets_CountryFlag">
                <div class="jx_ui_html_div flag flag-nz" data-test-id="countryFlagIcon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div icons_cell"></div>
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div time_cell" data-test-id="timeCell">
            2 mins
        </div>
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div numbers_cell" data-test-id="chatsCell">
            -
        </div>
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div numbers_cell" data-test-id="visitsCell">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div page_cell referrer_cell" data-test-id="referrerCell">
            <div class="meshim_dashboard_components_visitors_visitorList_renderers_SearchEngine search_engine"></div>
            <span class="jx_ui_html_span">newfreespinsnodeposit.com</span>
        </div>
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div page_cell">
            <span class="jx_ui_html_span number_tag" data-test-id="viewingNumber">1</span>
            <span class="jx_ui_html_span" data-test-id="viewingPage">Justspin.com</span>
        </div>
        <div class="jx_ui_html_div" data-test-id="lastMsgCell">
            How do I get my no deposit 100 freespins on firejoker
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meshim_dashboard_components_visitors_visitorList_VisitorTag visitorlist_tags">
        <span class="jx_ui_html_span">
            <span class="tag" style="display: inline-block;">English Support</span>
        </span>
        <span class="jx_ui_html_span"></span>
        <span class="jx_ui_html_span">
            <span class="tag">justspin</span>
            <span class="tag">justspin</span>
            <span class="tag">justspin</span>
            <span class="tag">english</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need a way to visualize what the data and your DOM look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to resolve this using this code:

```
const incomingChatTags = $(incomingChat).find('.tag').get();
const tags = {};
for (let k = 0; k < incomingChatTags.length; k++) {
    const normalHolderTag = $(incomingChatTags[k])
      .text()
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/\s/g, '')
      .replace('.', '');
    if (tags[normalHolderTag]) {
      $(incomingChatTags[k]).remove();
    } else {
      tags[normalHolderTag] = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an idea:

- loop through the DOM elements
- save the normalized inner text to an array
- check on each element, if the normalized inner text is already in the array
- if so, delete the DOM element

As I see that, you can do this check in your example for-loop at the beginning.

**-- updated with example --**

Based on your comment I think you have to do the task from the other side: Just do the check in your loop width a storage array. Assuming a function called `normalize` to remove spaces, it should like this way:

```js
let usedTags = []; // storage array

for (let k = 0; k < incomingChatTags.length; k++) {
  var holderTag = $(incomingChatTags[k]);

  // remove spaces, lower case etc.
  var normalHolderTag = normalize(holderTag);

  // check if we run into this tag before
  if($.inArray(normalHolderTag, usedTags) > -1) {
    continue;
  }

  // add the tag to the storage array
  usedTags.push(normalHolderTag);        

  // here goes your code      
  switch (normalHolderTag) {
    case 'accountclosure':
      $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-accountclosure');
      $(incomingChatTags[k])
        .closest('div')
        .prepend($(incomingChatTags[k]));
      priorityVal += 200;
      break;
    case 'rg':
      $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-rg');
      priorityVal += 240;
      $(incomingChatTags[k])
        .closest('div')
        .prepend($(incomingChatTags[k]));
      break;
    case 'vip':
      $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-vip');
      $(incomingChatTags[k])
        .closest('div')
        .prepend($(incomingChatTags[k]));
      priorityVal += 300;
      break;
    case '21com': {
      const logo21 = chrome.extension.getURL('/images/21_thumb.png');
      $(incomingChatTags[k]).html(`<img src="${logo21}" />`);
      $(incomingChatTags[k]).addClass('ce-tag-logo');
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }    
}
```

Maybe I've got your problem wrong, but this seems for me to work.

Comment: Thanks @g4rf but if I save the normalized inner text to a new array I'm basically creating a new array of strings, not DOM elements hence I can't use that array in order to do changes to the actual DOM. If you check the switch loop I'm doing a bunch of things with those dom elements depending on the innertext of the dom element (the span). Maybe I'm getting you wrong but I've tried this approach before and it doesn't work for me.